# XMLReader breaks on strange character

Tags: php, xml, parsing, encoding, xmlreader

Whenever XMLReader tried to parse this XML file Im feeding it, it breaks on "½" and on a period that looks like this "."

Both are characters that whenever I try to delete them from the xml feed, the editor deletes the characters in front of them first. So, they act like foreign/different encoding characters.

What are my options to fix it? I can't edit the xml file every time. Thanks a lot

Comment: What encode do you use in the feed? What encode do you use to read?

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?  This may be an encoding issue.

Comment: the feed says UTF-8 at the top, but I had to change it to ISO-8859-1 because it was breaking on a "é". To read it, Im using XMLReader's default which is UTF-8 I beleive. Thanks.

Comment: Well, here you discovered your problem. It's a encoding issue. You have to use the same encoding or, at least, convert to the same encoding before you use them.

Comment: How do I convert to the same encoding? Thanks a lot Aurelio. The file is 9MB, do I have to make my script load it into memory and re-encode it? Im worried about that too. Would that have a big impact in the amount of memory used?

Comment: @Michelle: [PHP Charset FAQ](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the program or process that creates the "XML" file. (I put "XML" in quotes, because actually, you would like it to be an XML file, but it isn't one.) You might be able to patch or repair or recover the data, but that's not a long-term solution.

The anecdotal evidence suggests that the "½" character is encoded as two bytes, suggesting it is encoded as UTF-8, while the "é" character is encoded as one byte, suggesting it is encoded as ISO 8859-1. That means that two different processes have written to the file, writing to it using different encodings. (Perhaps it was originally created in one encoding, and then modified using an editor that didn't know what the original encoding was.) That isn't going to work.